# Proof by induction of convergence of a recursively defined sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that the following sequence converges to a value of 1, but am unable to prove it through induction or any other means.

$$x_1=cos (1)$$
$$x_{n+1}=max(x_n,cos(n+1))$$

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence is increasing and obviously bounded by $1$, so it's convergent. Now, you also have that $x_n\geq \cos(n)$, so $\lim x_n\geq\limsup \cos(n)=1$. And therefore $\lim x_n=1$.

$\limsup\cos(n)=1$, comes from the fact that the sequence of  points corresponding to the angles $n$ in the unit circle (i.e. the sequence $(\cos n,\sin n)$) is dense in the unit circle. So, $\cos(n)$ can be arbitrary close to $1$.